# Dynamically allocate memory for vectors

Tags: c++, vector, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to replace arrays with vectors but I can't figure out how.

Replace this function to dynamically allocate memory for vectors:

```
string readFile(string filename, string** list, int size){
    *list = new string[size];
    ifstream file(filename);
    string line;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        getline(file, line);
        *(*list + i) = line;
    }

    file.close();
    return **list;
}
```

And here's my attempt to change it to vectors with no luck. Any feedback is greatly appreciated:

```
string processFile(string filename, vector<string>** list, int size){
        *list = new vector<string>(size);
        ifstream file(filename);
        string line;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            getline(file, line);
            *list[i] = line; // error
        }

        file.close();
        return **list; // error
    }
```

Comment: Just drop the pointers and the dynamic allocation. One of the reasons of using containers such as `std::vector` is that you don't have to do that kind of thing.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, however, our teacher is requiring us to use vector new.

Comment: Oh dear. Well, I hope they have a good reason for that, but I seriously doubt it. BTW there's another problem with your code: you loop over a certain number of lines without checking whether there are still lines to read in the file.

Answer (score 1):

You will need some proper error handling, but basically, you need neither pointers nor fixed sizes if you use containers:

```
std::vector<std::string> readLinesFromFile(const std::string& filename)
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    std::ifstream file(filename);

     for (std::string line; std::getline(file, line); )
     {
        result.push_back(line);
     }

     return result;
}
```

Comment: +1, but I suspect they need the function to read user-specified given number of lines, not the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems:

1. You don't need to use vector**, vector is equivalent to the list in previous code.
2. The return type is string, but you are returning vector**

This code should work, not tested though:

```
    void processFile(string filename, vector<string>& list, int size){
    //list = new vector<string>(size); // no need if you get a vector reference
    ifstream file(filename);
    string line;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        getline(file, line);
        list.push_back(line); //the error was because you are assigning string to a vector<string>*
    }

    file.close();
    // you dont have to return, as vector is passed by reference
}
```

If you still need to use pointer of vector

```
    void processFile(string filename, vector<string>** list, int size){
    *list = new vector<string>(size); // bad practice
    ifstream file(filename);
    string line;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        getline(file, line);
        (*list)->push_back(line); 
    }

    file.close();
    // you dont have to return,  as vector is passed by pointer
   }
```

Comment: In the second code snippet, `list` is local, so the called doesn't see any effect. Also, there is no need to call `file.close()`.

Comment: @RakibulHasan No, you missed on `&`. This is C++ :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change *list[i] = line to *list->push_back(line) and you should be okay for the first error.

The second error is going to depend on what your intent is for the return value. I think return *list->front(); will give the same result as the first example, but if you are planning on returning more than just the first line then you will need to do some concatenation. You can just create a local string and append each line as you read them.

Hopefully your teacher knows using new vector is almost always a code smell in C++ and is using this for a specific reason with a plan to fix it later.

Answer (score -1):

here is a working example. enjoy :)
BTW - you don't need to pass the length, just instantiate the memory and use the push_back method.

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void processFile(string filename, vector<string>** list, int size);
void main()
{
    vector<string>* list = NULL;
    processFile("C:\\temp.txt", &list, 13);
    int i = 1;
}

void processFile(string filename, vector<string>** list, int size){
    *list = new vector<string>();
    ifstream file(filename);
    string line;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        getline(file, line);
        (**list).push_back(line); // error
    }

    file.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all your inputs it is greatly appreciated.